# Mails goes to spam if domain name differs from send from domain name

Tags: php, laravel, sendgrid, spam, sparkpost

I do have a problem with mails going to spam.

Basically I do have web application stage and live service with different domain names.
If I do send mails from `xdomain.com` and use sending domain as `xdomain.com` mine mails goes to inbox, if I do send over app on `ydomain.com` and send from `xdomain.com` it goes to spam.

Is it a workaround on this or it's just how spam filters works and there is nothing I can do much about it?

Same problem occurs via `Sendgrid` or `SparkPost`.
I do use `Laravel` framework on my web app.
Thank you

Comment: I also have faced the same issue. What I did to resolve: make from email address' domain same as site's url.

Comment: Do both domains have the same IP address? Then the [SPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) should allow the mails.  Some mail providers have spam checks which put useful information in the mail header (e.g. `X-Spam-Status` for SpamAssassin). Do you have such tags in the mails treated as spam?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Send email from other domain without being spam!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460558/php-send-email-from-other-domain-without-being-spam)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use several mail channels(/drivers). And implement your own logic to switch between those.

The problem you are facing now is a result of using the "wrong" mail server. This creates suspicion for mail clients.